# Postgres EXPLAIN difference between 2 similar table with similar indices

Tags: postgresql

EDIT: As suggested by @zedfoxus, changing the string literal changes the plan.

```
sales=# EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM commercial_details WHERE record_type = 'SalesService::Rental';
                                                            QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using index_commercial_details_on_record_type_and_record_id on commercial_details  (cost=0.42..6.19 rows=1 width=2384)
   Index Cond: ((record_type)::text = 'SalesService::Rental'::text)
(2 rows)

sales=# EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM commercial_details WHERE record_type = 'SalesService::Sale';
                                  QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on commercial_details  (cost=0.00..19885.06 rows=153765 width=2384)
   Filter: ((record_type)::text = 'SalesService::Sale'::text)
(2 rows)
```

One string uses index scan, while the other uses sequential scan.  Would like to know what I can do so it both uses the index

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I've got 2 tables, sales and rentals, which are mostly similar, even in their sql indices.

I'm trying to copy data from a raw table into another table.  I'm transforming data along the way but I've removed that bit.

I'm trying to figure out why the rentals sql is taking too long compared to the sales sql.  Upon looking at the output of `EXPLAIN`, I get the following which made me wonder why there's a big difference between the 2 sql statements when the table's indices are very similarly set up.

```
sales=# EXPLAIN                                                                                                              
  SELECT *                                                                                                                      
  FROM raw_table raw_table
  JOIN rentals                                                                                                                    
    ON rentals.source_identifier = raw_table."SaleID"                                                            
    AND rentals.source = 'Test'                                                                                                    
    AND rentals.rp_data_transfer_id IS NULL                                                                                     
  LEFT JOIN commercial_details AS existing                                                                                        
    ON existing.record_id = rentals.id                                                                                            
    AND existing.record_type = 'Rental'                                                                           
  WHERE
    existing.id IS NULL
    AND "RecordType" = 'Lease';
                                                                QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=6.20..100273.39 rows=1 width=8018)
   Join Filter: ((rentals.source_identifier)::text = (raw_table."SaleID")::text)
   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=6.20..3265.98 rows=1 width=5030)
         Hash Cond: (rentals.id = existing.record_id)
         Filter: (existing.id IS NULL)
         ->  Seq Scan on rentals  (cost=0.00..3004.82 rows=67986 width=2646)
               Filter: ((rp_data_transfer_id IS NULL) AND ((source)::text = 'Test'::text))
         ->  Hash  (cost=6.19..6.19 rows=1 width=2384)
               ->  Index Scan using index_commercial_details_on_record_type_and_record_id on commercial_details existing  (cost=0.42..6.19 rows=1 width=2384)
                     Index Cond: ((record_type)::text = 'SalesService::Rental'::text)
   ->  Seq Scan on raw_table  (cost=0.00..96171.09 rows=66906 width=2988)
         Filter: (("RecordType")::text = 'Lease'::text)

sales=# EXPLAIN                                                                                                               
  SELECT *                                                                                                                      
  FROM raw_table raw_table
  JOIN sales                                                                                                                      
    ON sales.source_identifier = raw_table."SaleID"                                                              
    AND sales.source = 'Test'                                                                                                      
    AND sales.rp_data_transfer_id IS NULL                                                                                       
  LEFT JOIN commercial_details AS existing                                                                                        
    ON existing.record_id = sales.id                                                                                              
    AND existing.record_type = 'Sale'                                                                             
  WHERE
    existing.id IS NULL
    AND "RecordType" = 'Sale';
                                                            QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..250976.61 rows=1 width=7780)
   Join Filter: ((sales.source_identifier)::text = (raw_table."SaleID")::text)
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.42..152905.86 rows=1 width=4792)
         Filter: (existing.id IS NULL)
         ->  Seq Scan on sales  (cost=0.00..6716.71 rows=153727 width=2408)
               Filter: ((rp_data_transfer_id IS NULL) AND ((source)::text = 'Test'::text))
         ->  Index Scan using index_commercial_details_on_record_type_and_record_id on commercial_details existing  (cost=0.42..0.94 rows=1 width=2384)
               Index Cond: (((record_type)::text = 'Sale'::text) AND (record_id = sales.id))
   ->  Seq Scan on full_vipa_commercial_sales  (cost=0.00..96171.09 rows=151973 width=2988)
         Filter: (("RecordType")::text = 'Sale'::text)
```

There is an index on the `commercial_details` table for `record_id` and `record_type`.  I don't know why when it comes to rentals, it's not using that index.

Sales indexes

```
Indexes:
    "sales_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_sales_on_rpdata_property_id" btree (rpdata_property_id)
    "index_sales_on_source" btree (source)
    "index_sales_on_source_identifier" btree (source_identifier)
```

Rentals indexes

```
Indexes:
    "rentals_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_rentals_on_rpdata_property_id" btree (rpdata_property_id)
    "index_rentals_on_source" btree (source)
    "index_rentals_on_source_identifier" btree (source_identifier)
```

Commercial details indexes

```
Indexes:
    "commercial_details_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_commercial_details_on_record_type_and_record_id" btree (record_type, record_id)
```

Comment: We don't know how long either took.  Show an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), that way we will know.

Comment: sorry it's a bit irrelevant to the question.  I'm wondering why the ANALYZE output is different for both when they have similar indexes.

Comment: @jvnill I don't know the answer. I suggest comparing explain of a subset of both queries and add more statements till you find which statement introduces the difference.

Comment: @zedfoxus ahh I did that already.  it's the `LEFT JOIN` bits that's introducing the difference.  but even with that info, I'm stumped on what needs to be changed

Comment: @jvnill you are a step ahead already. Can you change `AND existing.record_type = 'Sale'` to `AND existing.record_type != 'Fictitious'` in both queries and see if the explain is the same? If it is the same, that could indicate that PG may be using different plans based on the different string literal `Sale` and `Rental`.

Comment: @zedfoxus you're spot on.  Using the sales sql, I changed `Sale` to `Rental` and I get a different `EXPLAIN`

Comment: @zedfoxus sorry, full disclosure, I was using a different string for record_type.  Using just `Sale` and `Rental` has no difference.  The actual string we are using is `SalesService::Sale` and `SalesService::Rental`

Comment: @jvnill good information! If you were to cast record_type and the string literals SalesService::Rental and SalesService::Sales to char(50), I am guessing that your execution plan will be the same for both.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the SELECT * some indexes won't be used until they have all the columns of the table. If the cost of using an index PLUS the join to the table to retrieve all the colums that are not inside the index definition, is greater than a simple table scan, the index won't be used.

You can try to create covering indexes by the use a the recently intriduced INCLUDE clause to confirl this hypothesis.

By the way, there is no index including the column "RecordType" for the raw_table ...

Comment: hi thanks for that but this doesn't answer the question on why the results of EXPLAIN are different

Comment: Because  estimated_cardinality * row_length differs.